# ¿Cómo hacer que me muestre el último producto en vez del primero?

Tags: php, mysql, web

tengo una página que subo productos y en la página principal aparecen todos pero ordenados del primero al último. A mi me gustaría que el último producto que subí quede de primero y los últimos hasta el final.

Si no se entiende lo que digo le puedo explicar mejor. Aquí les dejo el código, espero que por favor alguien me pueda ayudar:

```
<?php
$ret=mysqli_query($con,"select * from products");
while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($ret)) 
{
    # code...


?>

                                
        <div class="col-sm-14 col-md-10 wow fadeInUp">
            <div class="products">
                
    <div class="product">       
        <div class="product-image">
            <div class="image">
                <a href="product-details.php?pid=<?php echo htmlentities($row['id']);?>">
                <img  src="admin/productimages/<?php echo htmlentities(1);?>/<?php echo htmlentities($row['productImage1']);?>" class="img-responsive">  </a> 
            </div><!-- /.image -->          

                                               
        </div><!-- /.product-image -->
            
        
        <div class="product-info text-left">
            <h3 class="name"><a href="product-details.php?pid=<?php echo htmlentities($row['id']);?>"><?php echo htmlentities($row['productName']);?></a></h3>
            <div class="rating rateit-small"></div>
            <div class="description"></div>

            <div class="product-price"> 
                <span class="price">
                    $.<?php echo htmlentities($row['productPrice']);?>          </span>
                                             <span class="price-before-discount">$.<?php echo htmlentities($row['productPriceBeforeDiscount']);?>   </span>
                                    
            </div><!-- /.product-price -->
            
        </div><!-- /.product-info -->
                    <div class="action"><a href="index.php?page=product&action=add&id=<?php echo $row['id']; ?>" class="lnk btn btn-primary">Agregar a carrito</a></div>
            </div><!-- /.product -->
      
            </div><!-- /.products -->
        </div><!-- /.item -->
    <?php } ?>
```

Comment: Simplemente añade `order by CampoDeTuIDEnLaTabla desc` a la query y ya te vendrán ordenados con el último de primero. Ordenar una query es algo ***MUY BÁSICO*** y te recomiendo estudiar un poquito de sql si pretendes utilizar una base de datos... hay cosas que son mucho más fáciles de hacer si la query ya te devuelve exactamente lo que necesitas :)

Comment: Benito muchas gracias me funciono perfecto, si tengo que que estudiar mucho mas

Comment: ***Siempre*** vas a tener que estudiar más, los programadores nunca dejamos de tener que estudiar :) El caso es ir poco a poco para evitar quemarte! Feliz aprendizaje